# Schemas in Gmail: Can using schema JSON be considered malicious/spam by some clients?

Tags: google-schemas

I know some clients treat emails with javascript as spam/malicious even if the script is disabled or blocked, so would using the JSON-LD potentially lead to being flagged?

```
    <script type="application/ld+json"> ...</script>
```

I know it's not javascript per se and the type is not "text/javascript" but is there any reason to think some clients would flag it? Is it 'safer' to use the metadata/XML way instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend XML to appeal to  GMAIL functionality as well as other services.

< script > tags embedded in content can and will raise a flag with some email services, mostly the older and lesser used ones.

However, if your target market are GMAIL and other modern web services, you should have no problem with using JSON or script tags, since they are sandboxed anyway.

Comment: I'm asking specifically about [Schemas in Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/), which requires one of the two (JSON-LD or XML/metadata) to have interactions within the gmail inbox.

Comment: Gmail is not going to automatically flag this markup as SPAM. I haven't heard of other mail clients blocking it. There are many large companies using JSON-LD markup in their emails so even if there are some smaller mail clients that flag it improperly it shouldn't take them long to see a lot of false positives and update their filters.

Answer (score 0):

Any email you send with a script tag would probably be flagged.